# python3 and scrapy path

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

1、python3 program, how to  import modules from different directories 
2、How do I get path information of scrapy 
[image]
3、from RUGplatform.custom_module.rule_module import CrawlRule, ParserRule
   ImportError: No module named 'RUGplatform'

Comment: duplicate question, please refer below post.
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Thank you,but my question may be different，I want to know what the framework does

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/'.join(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0].split('/')[0:-2]))<br>
from RUGplatform.custom_module.rule_module import CrawlRule, ParserRule
```

Is there a more elegant solution? For example, the solution from scrapy framework